# Python - maximum number of terms added of a series such that sum < 5?

Tags: python

Hi I was asked the following:

Consider the series
Total = 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 .... + 1/N
What is the maximum number of terms added (i.e. the value of N) such that Total < 5.0? 
(write a few lines of Python code stopping when the sum is just less than 5.0)

So far thats what i did:

```
m = 5
n= 0
u = 1
sum_serie = 0

for u in range(1,100):
   u = 1/(n+1)
   n= n+1

   while u < m:

     sum_serie = sum_serie + u

   print(sum_serie)
   print(n)
```

it doesn't work. could someone explain? is there an easier way of doing it?
thanks

Comment: `len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n < 5.0, itertools.accumulate(itertools.count(1), lambda x, y  : x + 1/y))))` BOOM~~

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps the corrected version:

```
m = 5
n = 0
sum_series = 0

while sum_series < m:
  u = 1. / (n + 1)
  sum_series = sum_series + u
  n = n + 1

print(sum_series)
print(n)
```

which prints:

```
5.00206827268
83
```

First your `while` loop should have the condition `sum_serie < m` and parts `u = 1. / (n + 1)` and `n = n + 1` should be within that loop as shown. The `for` loop doesn't do what you need so it has been removed.

Comment: just wondering what is the purpose of the dot at the 1 at u = 1. / (n + 1) ?

Comment: @Hannah it makes it a `float`.  it may be clearer if it said `1.0` but it means the same thing

Comment: In newer versions of Python `1/2` is `0.5` but older versions `1/2` is `0`. The dot makes the numerator a float and thus `1./2` is `0.5`.

Comment: also why is the result > 5 ? shouldn't it be <5?

Answer (score 0):

To loop to the number just below the limit, just check the limit as a loop condition (here in a `while`) and change the value inside the loop. Something like;

```
limit = 5
n = 0
sum_serie = 0

while sum_serie + 1./(n+1) < limit:
  sum_serie += 1./(n+1)
  n += 1

print(sum_serie)
print(n)
```

For your data, you get the output;

```
4.9900200799090815
82
```